# Additional email recipient based on payment method Ids in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, email-notifications, payment-method

I am trying to add additional email recipient based on payment method Id on WooCommerce "New order" email notification.

Here is my code:

```
function at_conditional_admin_email_recipient($recipient, $order){
 //   if( ! is_a($order, 'WC_Order') ) return $recipient;
   
    if ( get_post_meta($order->id, '_payment_method', true) == 'my_custom_gateway_id' ) {
        $recipient .= ', xx1@xx.com';
    } else {
        $recipient .= ', xx2@xx.com';
    }
    return $recipient;
    
    
};
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'at_conditional_admin_email_recipient', 10, 2 );
```

But the hook doesn't seem firing my function. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is outdated since Woocommerce 3, try the following instead:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'payment_id_based_new_order_email_recipient', 10, 2 );
function payment_id_based_new_order_email_recipient( $recipient, $order ){
    // Avoiding backend displayed error in Woocommerce email settings (mandatory)
    if( ! is_a($order, 'WC_Order') ) 
        return $recipient;

    // Here below set in the array the desired payment Ids
    $targeted_payment_ids = array('bacs');
   
    if ( in_array( $order->get_payment_method(), $targeted_payment_ids ) ) {
        $recipient .= ', manager1@gmail.com';
    } else {
        $recipient .= ', manager2@gmail.com';
    }
    return $recipient;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

> Also sometimes the problem can be related to a wrong payment method Id string in your code (so try first for example with WooCommerce "cod" or "bacs" payment methods ids, to see if the code works).